# How can i update my apps live tile?

Tags: c#, windows-phone-7

How can I update my time every 10 mins? Or 30 mins? with a new image and text?

The image is stored locally on the phone and the text is just a name.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Update live tiles:

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/hh202948%28v=vs.92%29.aspx

Background agents (run every 30 mins), see `PeriodicTask`:

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/hh202942%28v=vs.92%29.aspx